# Python create materialized path in following sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a materialized path using python in like below sequence.

Expected seq.

0001, 0002, 0003, 0004, 0005, 0006, 0007, 0008, 0009, 000A, 000B, 000C, .... 000Z, 0010, 00011 and so on.

Basically, I have n number of elements in a list and I want to give a unique sequence number to every element in that list in the above manner.

```
mylist = [1,2,3,...n]
for i in mylist:
    # code to generate sequence number.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import itertools

l = [str(x) for x in list(range(10))] + [chr(x) for x in range(65, 91)]

want = ["".join(x) for x in itertools.product(l, l, l, l)]
print(want[:10])
#['0000', '0001', '0002', '0003', '0004', '0005', '0006', '0007', '0008', '0009']
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for integer list

```
for i in my_list:
    print("{:04d}".format(i))
```

and this for all

```
for i in my_list:
    print(str(i).zfill(len(str(1000))))
```

Comment: what about alphabets they are not coming.

Comment: not wroking showing only numbers 0001
0002
0003
0004
0005
0006
0007
0008
0009
0010
0011
0012
0013
0014
0015
...

Comment: but in `my_list` you only passed numbers

Comment: this want i am looking for the list may contain any data

Comment: i want to check the list count and then iterate it

Comment: have you tried second solution `print(str(i).zfill(len(str(1000))))` which i updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209777/discussion-between-c-grey-and-pruthvi-barot).